# Assign TextBox Text into variables

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to send an email from my Windows Forms Application.

I have created a form for getting mail_id and password.

- `Textbox1` is for getting mail_id.
- `Textbox2` is for getting password.

The user enters the same in those textboxes.

How can I assign the typed credentials in two different variables, so that I can use those variables further in my program?

e.g.:`text in textbox1= some variable;text in textbox2= another variable;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply:

```
string firstVal = textbox1.Text;
string secondVal = textbox2.Text;
```

But this is basic! Take a book and learn the basics, please.

Comment: sorry...i am a beginner in c#..anyway thankkss...

Comment: You might accept and/or upvote the answers that helped ;-)
Btw.: A free pdf beginners book is avaliable here: http://www.programmersheaven.com/ebooks/csharp_ebook.pdf

Answer (score 1):

```
string username = textbox1.Text;
string password = textbox2.Text;
```